# which adapter to use for dynamic grid image view

Tags: android, imageview, android-viewpager

I am having a `GridView` which adds images dynamically and on clicking the image we get an enlarge `ImageView`. I want to add swipe functionality to it. It should be dynamic and be able to load image if user reaches to last image while swiping.

Currently I am using view pager but when the last image is reached I am having trouble while updating the adapter, dealing with how to update `ViewPager`'s size, setting current position... . So any other method to sort this out is welcome

Answer (score 1):

you can use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)
with the layout of [RecyclerView GirdLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html)
the items in the Adapter will be displayied in a GridLayout